# End a express.js request based on conditional statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using the `Model.findOne` method from mongoose to find and add some new data into a document. What kind of data is added is based on conditional `if` statements. See below:

```
companyTotal.findOne({companyName: "xyz"}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)
        } else if (doc) {

                if (req.body.q1 === "poor") {
                    doc.poor += 1;
                } else if (req.body.q1 === "okay") {
                    doc.okay += 1;
                } else if (req.body.q1 === "well") {
                    doc.well += 1;
                } else if (req.body.q1 === "very well") {
                    doc.veryWell += 1;
                } else {
                    sendJsonResponse(res, 401, {"message": "Wrong data entry."})
                }
        }
        doc.save(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)
            } else {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data);
            }
        });

    });
```

If none of the conditional statements are met I want to end the request and send an error message back. I am using the `sendJsonResponse` function to handle any kind responses that need to be sent to the user along with the status codes.

```
function sendJsonResponse(res, status, content) {
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
}
```

Based on my knowledge `res.json` calls `res.end();` which then ends the request. But everytime the condition is not met it displays the error message BUT still runs the `doc.save()` method and adds the data into the document.

What am I doing wrong? How can I end a request within `if` statements if conditions are not met?

Comment: @AJS its already inside it. Its placed right before the closing brackets for `companyTotal.findOne().`

Comment: Try add "return" before res.json(content);

Comment: Try this: `function sendJsonResponse(res, status, content) {
  return res.status(status).json(content);
}`

Comment: @TanLe I tried the return statement. It still adds the data and gives me `can't set headers after they are sent` error.

Comment: @Niezborala I tried the return statement. It still adds the data and gives me `can't set headers after they are sent` error.

Comment: @Skywalker I think you can try with this `return sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)` or `sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err); return ;`

Comment: @Skywalker because in your function `sendJsonResponse` you send two responses. One with status, second one with json. Try to change this two lines to one: `return res.status(status).json(content);`

Answer (score 0):

define flag variable as

```
flag=0 ;
```

Then

```
else {
        flag++;
        sendJsonResponse(res, 401, {"message": "Wrong data entry."})
      }
```

Then

```
if (flag ==0 ){  
doc.save(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)
            } else {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data);
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try this and let you know but I really want to know why calling `sendJsonResponse` is not ending the request. In theory it should as its calling the `res.json`. Any thoughts on this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Skywalker about the reason , have a question about that in here, you can have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314598/in-express-js-why-does-code-after-res-json-still-execute

Comment: @Skywalker it is ending the request but due to node asynchronous nature   doc.save() getting called before response end. Btw does that worked ?

Comment: Still having issue ?

Comment: @AJS I tried your approach and its giving me the same issue.

Comment: ohhh thats quiet viyard. Do u have team viewer ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it should look like this:

```
function sendJsonResponse(res, status, content) {
  return res.status(status).json(content); // you can send response only one 
}
```

and:

```
companyTotal.findOne({companyName: "xyz"}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        return sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
    } else if (doc) {
            if (req.body.q1 === "poor") {
                doc.poor += 1;
            } else if (req.body.q1 === "okay") {
                doc.okay += 1;
            } else if (req.body.q1 === "well") {
                doc.well += 1;
            } else if (req.body.q1 === "very well") {
                doc.veryWell += 1;
            } else {
                return sendJsonResponse(res, 401, {"message": "Wrong data entry."});
            }
    }
    doc.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
        } else {
            return sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it but it still gives the same issue. I think the issue is that I use `sendJsonResponse` when my condition is not met but somehow the request does not stop there and goes onto `doc.save` which also runs `sendJsonResponse`` and thats what causing the 2nd response to be sent. The request should end when the first `sendJsonResponse` runs.

Comment: @Skywalker thats why I add `return` statements before all `sendJsonResponse` call.

Comment: I copy pasted your answer and tried it. It still giving the same error and issues.